# How do I bind keys to a command or a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I bind keys to a command or a function?
For example I want to bind D to window.alert("Hi")

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ha8ubs39/1/

Comment: Thanx it healped a lot

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a listener for the event fired when you push a key. You could see a good example [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwfxum.php)

Comment: thx it helped al little